# Elasticsearch, what is a type?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, types

In many article i read that types in elasticsearch are the same like tables in relational databases.

But then i read thats types have always commonalities (e. g. properties), 
this is a contradiction to the first statement, because in relational databases you can have so many tables they doesn't have any commonalities.

What is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type is basically just an additional metadata description, which gets stored as a field in the inverted index.

The important part to know is that types will be removed from Elasticsearch. In the next major version you will be only able to create indices with a single type, so it can be removed over the next major versions.

You may want to read this documentation about it https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/removal-of-types.html